# Package "@notifee/react-native" does not contain a valid config plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Expo react-native app compilation erro: Package "@notifee/react-native" does not contain a valid config plugin.

I'm using

- "expo": "^49.0.13"
- "react": "18.2.0"
- "react-native": "0.72.5"
- "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0"

I would appreciate your help.

I tried to upgrade my dependencies to the latest, but getting same issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [github thread](https://github.com/invertase/notifee/issues/799); `@notifee/react-native` expo plugin was removed in v7.8.0 and is no longer required.

so you can just remove it from `app.config.ts` `plugins` and your app should compile.